# CSS Handling in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Layout page in my MVC project displays the following code:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

I also read that this will ask for the files defined in the RegisterBundles method (in the BundleConfig class in the App_Start folder to be precise).

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
"~/Content/bootstrap.css",
"~/Content/site.css"));
```

But somehow my changes in Content/bootstrap.css won't go through. My MVC project only renders the Content/bootstrap.min.css, only changes in that file will change the styling of my MVC project. Can anyone explain me or direct me somewhere I can read about how changing CSS code in MVC works? Is it necessary to always change the bootstrap.min.css? I thought there must be some other way to change CSS code.

Comment: Have you tried refresh your browser cleaning the cache (with ctrl f5)?

Comment: Yes I already tried doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Bundling will use a min.css file if it exists as this is quicker for on-the-fly bundling as no dynamic minification is required.

Therefore either remove your `.min.css` file, or ensure this is updated whenever your `.css` file is.

Comment: Ah I think this is what is causing my question then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

in the `Application_Start()` of your `Global.asax.cs` file. This will disable the automatic using of the minimized files.

You can see more about this from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundletable.enableoptimizations(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Here is a nice article too: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: This will also remove minification in general, and bundling. `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` should only really be used in dev, otherwise theres no point using BundleConfig at all.

Comment: @Curt Well, in dev mode this is enabled by default, since you can assume that `compilation debug="true"`